# Understanding what is this "Delegate"?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm learning Objective-C, and I have to do one app. What I'm trying to do, is call from my `MainViewController`, a `SplitViewController`, in code. That's already solved. Now, I have to call multiple `DetailViewControllers`. I've found this example:
 http://kshitizghimire.com.np/uisplitviewcontroller-multipledetailviews-with-navigation-controller/

In this example, they use `MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate` to declare `SplitViewController` and `MasterViewController`, because the `SplitViewController` is loaded from the start, in the first `ViewController`, and using the `didFinishLaunching` function, of the `AppDelegate`. In my app, I'm loading the `SplitViewController` in the second `ViewController`, so my `SplitViewController` is declared and loaded in my `ViewController`, not in my `AppDelegate`. I've read, that "delegates" are like `Interfaces`, to declare and implement methods in different way, but here there are not using protocols or delegate methods. So, I have to do other `AppDelegate` for my `SecondViewController`, and declare in this new `AppDelegate` the `SplitViewController` and `MasterViewController`?... Or is this `AppDelegate` variable reference, just to reference to `SplitViewController`?

Comment: Read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AppArchitecture/AppArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Cocoa Core Competencies](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html):

> Delegation is a simple and powerful pattern in which one object in a
>   program acts on behalf of, or in coordination with, another object.
>   The delegating object keeps a reference to the other object—the
>   delegate—and at the appropriate time sends a message to it. The
>   message informs the delegate of an event that the delegating object is
>   about to handle or has just handled. The delegate may respond to the
>   message by updating the appearance or state of itself or other objects
>   in the application, and in some cases it can return a value that
>   affects how an impending event is handled. The main value of
>   delegation is that it allows you to easily customize the behavior of
>   several objects in one central object.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, do I have to have an AppDelegate for every ViewController? and change my "delegate" every time I'm changing my view so this way to pass the control to my new ViewController?